# Same code, different answer? Project Euler8

Tags: java

So, I was working on proj euler 8 and eventually got frustrated and cheated. I saw the answer I found https://github.com/nayuki/Project-Euler-solutions/blob/master/java/p008.java worked the same way my did with different code, but whenever I got a different answer.

So I changed lines and began copying his code to see where the flaw was, but eventually, when I'd changed everything and made my code the exact same as his (with different variable names), I still got a different answer. Can somebody explain to me why this is happening? The first is my code, the second is his.

```
public class Attempt {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
            System.out.println(new Attempt().getAnswer());
    }


    private static final String BIG_NUMBER = "I copied and pasted his number here, so no difference. I won't write it out since it's 1000 digits."
    private static final int ADJACENT = 13;

    public String getAnswer() {
            long highest = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i + ADJACENT <=BIG_NUMBER.length(); i++ ) {

                    long currentProduct = 1;

                    for (int thirteen = 1; thirteen < ADJACENT; thirteen++)

                            currentProduct *= BIG_NUMBER.charAt(i + thirteen) '0';


                    highest = Math.max(currentProduct, highest);

            }
            return Long.toString(highest);
    }

}


public class Cheat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(new Cheat().run());
    }


    private static final String NUMBER = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801$
    private static final int ADJACENT = 13;


    public String run() {
            long maxProd = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i + ADJACENT <= NUMBER.length(); i++) {
                    long prod = 1;
                    for (int j = 0; j < ADJACENT; j++)
                            prod *= NUMBER.charAt(i + j) - '0';
                    maxProd = Math.max(prod, maxProd);
            }
            return Long.toString(maxProd);
    }

}
```

Comment: "_my code the exact same as his_" One loop starts at 0, the other starts at 1. The codes are not the same.

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile:  `currentProduct *= BIG_NUMBER.charAt(i + thirteen) '0';` that's a fairly significant difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
 for (int thirteen = 1; thirteen < ADJACENT; thirteen++)  // Not 0 based
     currentProduct *= BIG_NUMBER.charAt(i + thirteen) '0'; // Error
```

Should be changed to:

```
   for (int thirteen = 0; thirteen < ADJACENT; thirteen++)
       currentProduct *= BIG_NUMBER.charAt(i + thirteen)- '0';
```

PS: `int thirteen` sounds like its a constant, use a better name instead.

Answer (score 1):

Java `String`(s) and array(s) start at `0` (not `1`).

```
for (int thirteen = 0; thirteen < ADJACENT; thirteen++)
```

**or** (I'm assuming you had a typographical error when missing the minus sign for '0' below)

```
currentProduct *= BIG_NUMBER.charAt(i + thirteen - 1) - '0';
```

*Note* the `i + thirteen - 1`. Also, your variable name of `thirteen` seems rather less descriptive than `j`... at least I wouldn't be tempted to think that `j` is always equal to `13`.